# Best way to import models from a bunch of different django projects

Tags: python-3.x, django

Basically I have a project that has a bunch of microservices and a number of databases across them.

What I want is to create another service that I can run different scripts on that make some changes to the prod db. For example if there was a bug that messed up some records, I'd have to go in to the prod db and fix those records.

What would be the best way to import all these models? I want to be able to do something like

service_a.db.ModelA

service_b.db.ModelB

etc

Or is there a package I can use to do this already instead of trying to build my own?